# Desktop flashes, does not load

Tags: windows-8, taskbar, desktop, windows-8.1

Almost every time I update my Windows 8.1, the whole thing breaks.  After login (which takes an unusually long time), the taskbar will appear with only the Start button (mapped to Classic Shell).  The desktop background also appears.  About half a second later, the screen flashes black, and the process repeats forever.  Ctrl-Alt-Delete does bring up the security options, etc.  If I log out and log back in, it repeats.  If I log in with a different account, same thing.  Sometimes I can reboot and it is fixed, but not anymore.  Everything works except the Desktop, however I can open the Task Manager and it will stay open.  I cannot run a command from it though.  I could fix it with a System Restore, but the latest one was saved when updates were ready to install.  So I restore, it reboots, updates, and I'm back where I started.  I cannot access the Metro interface because of mapping to Classic Shell.  The charms do not work.  I think it doesn't have enough time to show them before it reloads the Desktop.  I need this fixed, because my college campus blocks computers without current updates from connecting until they're up to date.  Please help!

Comment: Do these problems happen without Classic Shell installed?  Until you get rid of Classic Shell in order to limit instabilities with Windows 8.1 we cannot help.

Comment: @Ramhound The latest versions claim full support for 8.1 . . .  It even uses the new Start button already in 8.1.

Comment: Also, why was I downvoted?

Comment: OK, the real solution I found was to wait it out for about a year.  I re-enabled Windows Update, and no flashing was to be found upon a reboot after updating.  Wyatt's answer was accepted because it's helpful advice in most cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try removing classic shell, either by booting to safe mode (which windows 8 has made much harder to access) or by booting a live usb and removing the classic shell registry entries w/ chntpw 's registry editor.

Additional information added December 6, 2013:
You might be able to get away with reinstalling classic shell after updating, but I would make a disk image backup before attempting that. Just to be safe!

This happened to me a while back. I didn't update to 8.1 though, it was just a minor update inside windows 8.0 (I know it's technically NT 6.2.9200). I hope it never happens again to either of us!